# Multiple Dependent drop down list in excel/vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do sector classification for GICS sector. GICS structure consists of 11 sectors, 24 industry groups, 69 industries and 158 sub-industries. the below link gives the sector classfication

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Industry_Classification_Standard

can i create a drop down list like the attached image using data validation and name range function ?

like this with a vba button to refresh

[image]

Comment: there is one more point which i would like to put, for eg if we create a dependent list and if one changes the second and third column then one should not be able to change the first column else it will give erroneous result.

Comment: I don't think this question qualifies for help on this forum because your own effort is not in evidence.

Comment: @variatus : i have done my homework, here is the link
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/mwezhcqn2datyw63w33rg/Sector.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=5pydtvv0qyeb8r33ee4z20cpz

Answer (score 0):

On the web there are many step-by-step guides to create interdependent validation drop-downs. [This is one of them](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/09/30/dependent-cascading-dropdown-lists-excel/#dynamic-cascading-dropdown). Working your way through the instructions is serious work. To help you on your way I have created a starting point for you.

[image]

The picture shows a table named `Industry_Groups`. It has one column for each group, and in this column are listed all the industries in that group. Now you can create a drop-down with all the column captions which would enable you to select any of the industry groups. This drop-down would have the list specification

```
=INDIRECT("Industry_Groups[#Headers]")
```

A dependent drop-down would have the list specification given below.

```
=INDIRECT("Industry_Groups["&A10&"]")
```

As you see, it takes the referenced table column name from cell A10, which is occupied by the first drop-down. Therefore the list in the second drop-down will change depending upon the selection in the first.

Of course, whatever can be selected in the second drop-down is nothing but the name of another list in another table. Each of them would name a table like the one shown above - literally hundreds of them. They have to be created before you can start on the programming.

Talking of programming, it seems that you tried to create a VBA based system that would generate the lists on the fly. No doubt that is possible but it would require some serious programming for which your attempts do not show an aptitude. The advantage of the system I show you here is that you can create and implement it with your own resources. You know, it's the story of the sparrow in your hand and the pigeon on the roof.

Comment: i have created industry_group for each sector (total 11 columns created) now should i create name range for each column/industry_group ? for instance i tried =INDIRECT("Industry_Groups[Financials]") and getting ref# error

Comment: This error in data validation : "The source currently evaluates to an error. Do you want to continue?" would you be able to help if i give all the sector, industry_groups, industry, sub_groups organised in a sheet ?

Comment: i have created further classification of sectors for Industry. Can you pls have a look and suggest what is wrong. Main sheets are "Sector details" and "sheet2".
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/7d0qs8ni5w0bhecacx53k/Sector-New.xlsm?dl=0&rlkey=67lp8zp7xabcwfvc7xs7vc8e5

Comment: First off: **Now** you've done your homework :-)  But you need to be more systematic in naming and marking. Your drop-down "Sector" only lists Industry Groups which are taken from a range called "Header" (on "Sheet2") which nobody can find unless one knows where it is. Draw a box around each range with the name next to it. Don't use merged cells under any circumstances and consider that having more than one list per column will prevent you from making the ranges vertically dynamic in future.

Comment: For your data validation in Sector Details!C2 this formula will work, `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","_"))`

Comment: Thanks Variatus i will check tihs and confirm

Comment: can you pls confirm one more thing what name should i give to name ranges from industry ?

Comment: That's a tricky one. The GICS people already struggled with it and didn't find a good answer. I think you are stuck with what they found because your names must be linkable to the GICS system. I think your first table should have have "Sectors" in the header row and Industry Groups in each of the lists. Name each of these tables like "Grp_Banks", "Grp_RealEstate". The second table has "Industry Groups" in the header and lists of Industries in the columns, like "Ind_Banking", "Ind_RealEstate". The final one would have Industries in the header and columns like "Sub_DivBanking", "Sub_Reits" etc.

Comment: Consider creating a conversion table, i.e. a table that converts what the user selects to the name of the table that he means. In place of `=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE(B2," ","_"))` you would use a formula like this `=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(B2,[ConversionTable],2,False))`

Comment: Thanks Variatus, i will give it a try